# making sure a function does not use a global variable

Tags: r, scope

This maybe a bit converse to similar questions. I would like R to abort\warn if anywhere in the code, a function uses a variable in a parent environment. Is there some base option to achieve that? I would like a solution that is general for a session, not a particular check.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll find the `codetools` package of interest.

Comment: @Dason findGlobals() seems like what I looked for. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function `findGlobals` in the `codetools` package. Maybe this is helpful:

```
library(codetools)
x <- "global"
foo <- function() x

foo()
[1] "global"

findGlobals(foo)
[1] "x"
```