# Why does my R function have knowledge of variables that are not given as arguments?

Tags: r

I've notice that R functions can include variables that are not given as arguments. For example:

```
foo <- "hello world"
bar <- 10

test.fun <- function(){print(foo)}
test.fun()
[1] "hello world"
```

I would have expected "NULL", given my experience with other languages, however I get "hello world". I could understand this if "foo" was a global variable, but its not. Surely this function should have no knowledge of "foo" or "bar"?

What is going on here? And is there a way to stop it? In my mind this is dangerous as large code bases could contain the same variable names.

Comment: R has lexical scoping which means that variables not found in the current function scope are looked for in the environment where the function was defined. This is a core, useful feature for R and is not easy to disrupt because this would break a lot of things. Basic functions like `print()` are also not defined in your function scope so they would not work either if you didn't inherit them from somewhere. Maybe you can give a more specific example of what you are really doing and we can suggest possible alternatives.

Comment: For solutions/workarounds check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970939/r-scoping-disallow-global-variables-in-function

Comment: _"I could understand this if "foo" was a global variable, but its not."_  Yes it is. Check `ls(.GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: [This section](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping) from the book *Advanced R* might be helpful.